# Alternative to next(next(...)) to access n-th elemnt of iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I have a list iterator `children`  equivalent to `<list_iterator object at 0x050BAAF0>` (VS-Code debugger), and need to access the 4th element of that iterator, which I know for sure exists.

Is there a quick way, instead of calling 4 times `next(children)` to access an element at the n-th position in a list iterator, without having the list itself.

Thanks!

EDIT: here is some code: 
the iterator is actually the children of a BeautifulSoup node of a `div`

```
virgin_url = "https://www.clicpublic.be/product/_"
product_soup = get_soup(virgin_url + single_id + ".html") 
#get_soup returns the BeatutifulSoup([HTML of page])
bs_info_list = product_soup.findAll("div", {'class': "txtProductInformation"}
children = bs_info_list[0].children
```

Comment: See `nth` in the recipes section of the itertools documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: So do you have nested iterators like your "next(next(...))" implies or not?

Comment: Can't you use BeautifulSoup functionality for this? Can you share the relevant HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [itertool.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

next(islice(children, 3, None))
```

The 4th element has index 3

ex:

```
from itertools import islice

children = (e for e in range(100))
next(islice(children, 3, None))
```

output:

```
3
```